# What is uninitialized constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a new RoRs app.  It has one page and these configurations:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome' => 'mypages#home'
```

my_pages_controller.rb

```
class MyPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end
end
```

When I run the app at localhost:3000/welcome, I get this error:

> Routing Error
>
> uninitialized constant MypagesController

Any idea what is wrong?

localhost:3000 loads without issue.

Comment: what's the file name for `MypagesController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should match your underscore and camelCasing of classes:

`get 'welcome' => 'my_pages#home'` will match a controller named `MyPagesController`.

`get 'welcome' => 'mypages#home'` will match a controller named `MypagesController`

Answer (score 2):

When you have this route:

```
get 'welcome' => 'mypages#home'
```

Rails will look for `MypagesController`'s `home` action by default. But, in your case, you don't really have a controller with that name. That's why you are getting that error.

You should ideally change your route to this:

```
get 'welcome' => 'my_pages#home'
```

Then, Rails will look for `MyPagesController` which will match your existing controller and your code will work.

Alternatively, (not recommended in this case though), you could use `:controller` option in your route to tell Rails in which controller it should find the `home` action:

```
get 'welcome' => 'mypages#home', controller: "my_pages"
```

This would work too.